# Android Bluetooth SPP connection to embedded Linux board - PIN request

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a Nexus One, running Android 2.2, as the client. I want to make a socket connection to an embedded Linux board (Server). I have been able to get the connection up using the SPP UUID. My question has to do with pairing, actually why does the PIN request keep popping up every time I attempt to connect a socket, when the devices are already paired? Looking at logcat in DDMS it looks like the Linux board (Bluez 2.24) is requesting a PIN.

08-27 14:58:12.567: INFO/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(11816): agent_event_filter: Received method org.bluez.Agent:RequestPinCode

I have tried to reconfigure hcid.conf several ways, but I still get a pairing request on the Nexus One. Any ideas? I saw another post with no answers on trying to handle the pairing request programmatically. Is this the way to go?

Any help on the would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello, I know it's been long time ago, but did you managed to solve this issue? I'm stuck with similar problem. :(